# Is Robert Earl MacKenzie (co-author of Introduction to Differential Manifolds) still alive?

Tags: mathematicians

I am making sure that my information on certain mathematicians is up to date and accurate. To this end I am looking at Robert Earl MacKenzie, who (according to my records) was born March 17, 1920. I have scoured the internet for news of his passing, but the only results I have found are inconclusive: PraBook does not record a death date, and there are 2 obituaries: one for a 2011 date and one for a 2016 date (so possibly neither one). Unfortunately it is a not uncommon name, so there may be plenty of records that refer to different people.

Does anyone out there have any inside knowledge? He is listed in this book I have as being in the dept of mathematics at Indiana at some stage.

Comment: My records indicate that he was born in 1920 and died in 2012. Once you have a suspected death date, you can try googling, and just now I got [this newspaper article](https://www.hoosiertimes.com/herald_times_online/obituaries/obituaries-october-23-2012/article_9c059ffd-9c9f-58f4-975b-cf1e718cf43c.html) (not accessible by me, but what shows is sufficient to establish the 2012 death year). Incidentally, one way I've found death years is to include a year (in double quotes) in the search -- a year after the last year you can determine the person is alive -- and then increment year-by-year . . .

Comment: Incidentally, nothing so time-consuming as I suggested in my previous comment is needed for MacKenzie. The first thing I would have tried is ["Robert Earl MacKenzie" + math + "1920"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Robert+Earl+MacKenzie%22+math+%221920%22), and this brings up the newspaper article in my previous comment.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro My googling skill is even worse than my mathematical skill and (this is incredible) even worse than my attitude towards learning. So thanks for that.